# How to decompress Gzip files from EventHub using Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, gzip, spark-structured-streaming

Is there a way to read gzip files from Eventhub and decompress them using spark structured streaming, want to store uncompressed json at ADLS using Spark Structured Streaming Trigger once.

I'm getting NULL data when i tried to read the EventHub Data which is currently compressed via Spark Structured Streaming. I would need some logic how to decompress the EventHub data while reading.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by writing a scala UDF. Hope this may help somebody in the future.

```
 val decompress = udf{compressed: Array[Byte] => {
      val inputStream = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(compressed))
      scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(inputStream).mkString
    }}
```